# Visualisation issue with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a visualization thatchampion_radar_plot <- funct

```
ion(df, champion_name) {
  slam_win_cnt_chp = df %>% filter(WINNER == champion_name)
  chp_num_wins <- slam_win_cnt_chp$NUM_WINS
  l <- length(chp_num_wins)
  max_v <- 10 # choosing the same maximum value for all champions
  chp_df <- data.frame(rbind(max = rep(max_v, l), min = rep(0, l), chp_num_wins))
  colnames(chp_df) <- slam_win_cnt_chp$TOURNAMENT
  seg_n <- max_v
  radarchart(chp_df, axistype = 1, caxislabels = seq(0, max_v, 1), seg = seg_n,
             centerzero = TRUE, pcol = rgb(0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9) , pfcol = rgb(0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3),
             plwd = 1, cglcol = "grey", cglty = 1, axislabcol = "blue",
             vlcex = 0.8, calcex = 0.7, title = champion_name)
```

}

champion_radar_plot(slam_win_cnt, "Roger Federer")sv

Comment: Welcome. Please provide some context, as well as a specific question with your query.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is of help for you.

```
library("tidyverse")

slam_win <- read.csv("grand_slam_data.csv")
slam_win$tournament <- factor(slam_win$tournament)

slam_win %>% 
        filter(!tournament %in% c("Australian Open (Dec)", "Australian Open (Jan)")) %>% 
        group_by(tournament, winner) %>% 
        summarise(wins = n()) %>% 
        arrange(desc(tournament, wins)) %>% 
        slice_max(order_by = wins, n=3)
```

Turning tournament in a factor will you allow to group by it in either dplyr or Ggplot2.
The slice function will give you the n (you define it in the arguments) number of highest values of each group.

The next step is to plot

```
plot_slam <- slam_win %>% 
        filter(!tournament %in% c("Australian Open (Dec)", "Australian Open (Jan)")) %>% 
        group_by(tournament, winner) %>% 
        summarise(wins = n()) %>% 
        arrange(desc(tournament, wins)) %>% 
        slice_max(order_by = wins, n=3)

ggplot(plot_slam, aes(wins,  reorder(tournament, wins), fill = reorder(winner, wins))) +
        geom_col(position = position_dodge()) + 
        geom_text(aes(label = winner), position = position_dodge(0.9), hjust = 1.1)
```

You can add title and axis names by adding `labs(title = "Grand Slam Tournaments", x = "Number of wins", y = "Tournament")` and remove the legend via `theme(legend.position = 'none'`

This is the resulting:

[image]

Comment: thank you, what if i want to show the top 20 winners for each tournament?

Comment: if i change n=4, i am getting list of 22 players. but couldnot get top 20 players

Comment: if you want to get the top 20 players, change `slice_max(order_by = wins, n = 20)`. I wouldn't recommend to plot it though, as the bars are way to cramped.